# Finding when a noisy signal stabilizes

Tags: python, time-series

I have this data which is pretty noisy and is fluctuating over time. I want to find the x when the signal stabilizes. In this graph I can visually say it is somewhere between 1 and 2000. How do I find that point in python?

[image]

Comment: what is the input data? what is definition of a stable signal (e.g. level of variation)? Is the signal guaranteed to stabilize or there might be multiple noisy periods?

Comment: The signal is guaranteed to stabilize. I am defining the signal to be stable when the amplitude of the oscillations become constant. So in this case suppose the amplitude is decaying from around -0.3-0.3 to -0.1-0.1. But I have other signals where these ranges will be different

Answer (score 1):

You might consider looking at the variance of the data using a sliding window. When the variance drops below an acceptable threshold you can discard all previous points as noise. The tolerance is completely up to you and your application so you'll need to determine that yourself.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate a data set
N = 1000
t = np.linspace(0.1, 2, N)
signal = np.random.randn(N) / np.sqrt(t*0.8)

# create a sliding window view (50% overlap)
chunk_size = 100
chunks = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(signal, chunk_size)[::chunk_size//2]

# take the variance of the windows
var = np.var(chunks, axis=1)
t_var = t[::chunk_size//2][:var.size]

_, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, signal)
ax.plot(t_var, var, c='r', linestyle='', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the opposite problem (detecting where the signal becomes noisy) but the previous answer helped me to code the solution!
I leave the code in case you need it.

```
def get_variance_by_chunks(signal, chunk_size):
    t = np.arange(0, signal.size)
    # create a sliding window view (50% overlap)
    chunks = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(signal, chunk_size)[::chunk_size // 2]
    # take the variance of the windows
    var = np.var(chunks, axis=1)
    t_var = t[::chunk_size // 2][:var.size]
    return t_var, var

def min_max_normalization(vector):
    return (vector - np.nanmin(vector)) / (np.nanmax(vector) - np.nanmin(vector))


variance_window = 25
t_var, variance_by_windows = get_variance_by_chunks(signal, variance_window)
variance_by_windows = min_max_normalization(variance_by_windows)
# find point where variance overpass the threshold
variance_threshold = 2 # in percentage
over_threshold_index = np.nanmin(np.where(variance_by_windows > variance_threshold/100))
noise_starting_point_over_signal = t_var[over_threshold_index]
```

[signal and variance by chunks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CLdW.png)